# Regex find STRING, but ignore lines, that have //.* before STRING

Tags: regex, notepad++

In Notepad++ in javascript code I need to find lines, that have STRING, but except commented line (that have // and maybe some text before STRING).

```
//some text find_me=1
some text find_me=2
//find_me=3
find_me=4
just another line
find_me=6//
find_me=7 some text//
```

only 2 4 6 7 lines should be in search result.

Comment: Clarify which regex syntax you're using and do not spam tags.

Comment: You have not specified sufficiently what you want. I have no idea why "just another line" should not be matched. Are you trying to match only assignment expressions?

Comment: I think the OP wants to find all lines that contain "find_me", but only when there's no `//` before that.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I need regex syntax of javascript

Comment: @PedroCastilho Notepad++ allows to search code by regex. I want to search in huge javascript code in Notepad++, but exclude commented lines, "just another line" it is lines, that don't have "find_me" at all.

Comment: @JohannesEgger yes, you are right. Also no symbols between // and find_me like "//and some text find_me"

Comment: Do you know which regex syntax Notepad++ uses? This sounds like it will require negative lookbehind, which varies depending on regex syntax.

Comment: `^(?!//).*STRING`, let me find the duplicate…

Comment: @PedroCastilho Notepad++ regular expressions use the standard PCRE (Perl) syntax, I think it is similar to PHP syntax of regex.

Comment: @Ryan your regex don't work with "//some text find_me=1", it works only with "//find_me=1"

Comment: @SamAniston: You sure you didn’t just forget the `.*`?

Comment: @Ryan oh my God, it really works here:
https://regex101.com/r/uueM75/1
but it doesn't work correctly in Notepad++
There is some syntax difference maybe...

Comment: Okay, I’ll go get Notepad++ and try it. In the meantime, `^([^/].*|/|/[^/].*)?STRING` should probably work.

Comment: @Ryan unfortunately it `^([^/].*|/|/[^/].*)?STRING` doesn't works in Notepad++ but works on regex101.com

Comment: Erm, that’s extremely standard regex, though. What’s in `STRING`? Is regex mode actually enabled?